# MySQL - How to use input param having comma separated string value, in an IN clause

Tags: mysql, split

I have to query a table in MySQL based on a column which is of string type.

```
-----------------------------------
id  | lookupkeys  |   productid  |
-----------------------------------
1   |   key1      |     5GEH03   |
2   |   key2      |     7445DW   |
3   |   key3      |     9DSFDF   |
4   |   key4      |     5GEH03   |
5   |   keyN      |     7445DW   |
-----------------------------------
```

A stored procedure to accept multiple values (comma separated) in single input parameter which is to be used in IN clause.

```
Input : @keys = "key1,key5,key19,key22"
Query : SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE lookupkeys IN ("key1","key5","key19","key22");
```

So basically I need a way how to have this comma separated input to individual values for the IN clause ?

Below is a dummy sp

```
CREATE DEFINER=`xxx_xx`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_demo_fetch_products`(
    IN v_lookupkeys VARCHAR(200)
    )
BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM products_lookup WHERE lookupkeys IN(here I want to use v_lookupkeys)
        AND CONDITION_1
        AND CONDITION_2
        ORDER BY popularity DESC;
END$$
```

Comment: Show the stored procedure code and the `CALL`?  if `@keys` is set with `SET @keys := <>` in the stored procedure more or less like `SET @keys := p_in_key_param` it should be possible to use `IN(@keys)`

Comment: Why do you have a sproc? I see nothing 'procedural' here !?! But actually, I don't know what `this comma separated input to individual values for the IN clause` means.

Comment: *"Why do you have a sproc? I see nothing 'procedural' here !?"* very much agreeing here with @Strawberry ,  using a stored procedure here indeed does not seams to be justifiable, i wanted to wait making that comment before seeing the complete stored procedure code..

Comment: Well it was a pseudo code. Updated my question with dummy sp. Hope it helps